# How to find a good part-time programs by reputable business schools?

Tags: graduate-school

I have a bachelor degree and work for a marketing research company as a senior research analyst in Morris County in NJ. Having this day-time job, my options for further education remain part-time programs only. However, I do want to get a formal degree from reputable part-time programs, such as part-time MBAs/Master degree. Not just some random courses or certification training offered by community colleges or education institutions.

I work till 5:30 everyday so I am only available after that or on weekends. And the place of lecture has to be close enough to my office/home. Not some place too far away.

I am wondering if there are any programs meeting these criteria. I am not sure where to find, who to ask or which website I should look at to search for these kind of programs. Where should I start? What are the other things I should consider when I plan my further education and choose the programs?

Comment: Hi baoye, welcome to AcademiaSE! There seems to be two questions in your question: the one from the title (finding a a good part-time BS in NY), and the one at the end of your question (How do I find one?). The former is a bit too localised, but the latter is good. Could you please reformulate the title to reflect more the fact that you're looking for *ways* to find a good school?

Answer (score 1):

Baoye,
There are plenty of accredited online MBA programs at accredited institutions. In Maryland, where I am, [Frostburg State University](http://www.frostburg.edu/colleges/cob/mba/) offers an AACSB accredited MBA fully online. [University of Maryland University College](http://www.umuc.edu) also has a good online program. A little effort on Google should find other programs, perhaps even on New Jersey.